# Possible to 301 redirect using apache mod_rewrite to url with scheme that is not "http" and "https"?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Trying to do a 301 redirect using apache mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule /the-path/(.*) my-scheme://new-site.com/the-path/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The path http://site.com/the-path/param1=xyz will redirect to 
http://site.com/my-scheme://new-site.com/the-path/param1-xyz

But when I use "http" or "https" in place of "my-scheme" in the rewrite rule, it is working as expected.

So I guess mod_rewrite can redirect to only "http" or "https". Anyone can confirm? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not just "http:" or "https:", but [pretty close](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c?revision=1023063&view=markup#l473).

Comment: Useful to know. So for people who still need these redirects, one option would be to mod_rewrite to a PHP script (don't use a 30x code), and `header('Location: scheme://some.url/')` from there.